Select with pivot in SQL Server
I have migrated my MS Access database to SQL Server. I have a pivot query, which I am unable to adapt.
In MS Access, it is:
TRANSFORM FIRST(eff.efi) AS efici

SELECT eff.semana_ano, FIRST(eff.data), LAST(eff.data), ROUND(Avg(eff.efi), 2) AS media_semana
FROM 
    (SELECT dia_semana, semana_ano, efi 
     FROM tmp_lista) AS eff 
GROUP BY eff.semana_ano
PIVOT eff.ndia_semana

The data in SQL Server is:
CREATE TABLE tmp_lista
(   
    dia         date, 
    dia_semana  varchar(5), 
    semana_ano  int,
    efi         decimal(5,2) 
);

INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-01', 'D5', 5, 0.98);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-02', 'D6', 5, 0.5);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-03', 'D7', 5, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-04', 'D1', 6, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-05', 'D2', 6, 0.49);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-06', 'D3', 6, 0.65);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-07', 'D4', 6, 0.3);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-08', 'D5', 6, 1.18);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-09', 'D6', 6, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-10', 'D7', 6, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-11', 'D1', 7, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-12', 'D2', 7, 0.57);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-13', 'D3', 7, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-14', 'D4', 7, 0.51);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-15', 'D5', 7, 0.65);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-16', 'D6', 7, 0.49);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-17', 'D7', 7, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-18', 'D1', 8, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-19', 'D2', 8, 0.34);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-20', 'D3', 8, 0.46);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-21', 'D4', 8, 0.43);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-22', 'D5', 8, 0.32);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-23', 'D6', 8, 0.62);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-24', 'D7', 8, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-25', 'D1', 9, NULL);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-26', 'D2', 9, 0.62);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-27', 'D3', 9, 0.44);
INSERT INTO tmp_lista (dia, dia_semana, semana_ano, efi) VALUES ('2024-02-28', 'D4', 9, 0.54);



dia       |dia_semana|semana_ano|efi   |
----------|----------|----------|------|
2024-02-01|D5        |         5|  0.98|
2024-02-02|D6        |         5|  0.50|
2024-02-03|D7        |         5|[NULL]|
2024-02-04|D1        |         6|[NULL]|
2024-02-05|D2        |         6|  0.49|
2024-02-06|D3        |         6|  0.65|
2024-02-07|D4        |         6|  0.30|
2024-02-08|D5        |         6|  1.18|
2024-02-09|D6        |         6|[NULL]|
2024-02-10|D7        |         6|[NULL]|
2024-02-11|D1        |         7|[NULL]|
2024-02-12|D2        |         7|  0.57|
2024-02-13|D3        |         7|[NULL]|
2024-02-14|D4        |         7|  0.51|
2024-02-15|D5        |         7|  0.65|
2024-02-16|D6        |         7|  0.49|
2024-02-17|D7        |         7|[NULL]|
2024-02-18|D1        |         8|[NULL]|
2024-02-19|D2        |         8|  0.34|
2024-02-20|D3        |         8|  0.46|
2024-02-21|D4        |         8|  0.43|
2024-02-22|D5        |         8|  0.32|
2024-02-23|D6        |         8|  0.62|
2024-02-24|D7        |         8|[NULL]|
2024-02-25|D1        |         9|[NULL]|
2024-02-26|D2        |         9|  0.62|
2024-02-27|D3        |         9|  0.44|
2024-02-28|D4        |         9|  0.54|

I managed to adapt to this point:
SELECT
    semana_ano, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7 
FROM
    (SELECT dia_semana, semana_ano, efi FROM tmp_lista) AS dp 
PIVOT
    (SUM(efi) FOR dia_semana IN (D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7)) result_dp;

semana_ano|D1    |D2    |D3    |D4    |D5    |D6    |D7    |
----------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
5         |[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|  0.98|  0.50|[NULL]|
6         |[NULL]|  0.49|  0.65|  0.30|  1.18|[NULL]|[NULL]|
7         |[NULL]|  0.57|[NULL]|  0.51|  0.65|  0.49|[NULL]|
8         |[NULL]|  0.34|  0.46|  0.43|  0.32|  0.62|[NULL]|
9         |[NULL]|  0.62|  0.44|  0.54|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|

You would also need a column for the minimum day of the week, a column with the maximum day of the week, and a column with the average of the 7 days.
Something like:
semana_ano|D1    |D2    |D3    |D4    |D5    |D6    |D7    |min(dia)  |max(dia)  |avg(7 dias)|
----------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|----------|----------|-----------|
5         |[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|  0.98|  0.50|[NULL]|2024-02-01|2024-02-03|   0.74|
6         |[NULL]|  0.49|  0.65|  0.30|  1.18|[NULL]|[NULL]|2024-02-04|2024-02-10|   0.66|
7         |[NULL]|  0.57|[NULL]|  0.51|  0.65|  0.49|[NULL]|2024-02-11|2024-02-17|   0.56|
8         |[NULL]|  0.34|  0.46|  0.43|  0.32|  0.62|[NULL]|2024-02-18|2024-02-24|   0.43|
9         |[NULL]|  0.62|  0.44|  0.54|[NULL]|[NULL]|[NULL]|2024-02-25|2024-02-28|   0.53|


use conditional aggregation instead of pivot to get more flexibility, plenty of answers on how to do it here
